# Executing potentially expensive tasks

Tags: multithreading, node.js, process

I have a nodejs tcp server that handles the state of many child servers, when something happens the state server tells a child server to perform an action, it can be potentially expensive, most cases it will be quite expensive (around a minute), on some occasions it will be done in a couple of seconds.

Due to what the child servers are doing (listening on websockets and passing quite a lot of data back and forth very frequently), I can't afford to have the child server stall while operating this expensive task.

Obviously nodejs doesn't have the ability to spawn new threads, without some messy implementation of them. Would it be worth spawning a new process to execute this potentially expensive task, I can determine when it is going to be expensive by the command sent from the parent server.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use a message queue and create couple of worker processes instead?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js does have the ability to spawn other processes, and it handles them quite well. Check out child_processes in the node.js documentation, and specifically the fork command which allows you to spawn other node.js jobs and communicate with them via message channel.

[Node.js Child Processes](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html)
[Node.js Fork](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html#child_process.fork)

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html#child_process.fork

Comment: As the documentation says: "These child Nodes are still whole new instances of V8. Assume at least 30ms startup and 10mb memory for each new Node. That is, you cannot create many thousands of them." you can not create a lot of these. But it could work if you do not spawn that many processess.

Comment: Right. If it's an expensive operation as in the question, you shouldn't be spawning many of these processes anyway.

Comment: It seems that spawning processes is going to be more expensive than just letting it carry on in the parent process, I think I've found my answer, thanks.

Comment: Only as long as you don't mind the parent process being blocked for the duration of the task. Keep in mind that they won't be able to handle any other incoming requests until that long process finishes.